# MATLAB - Keep getting empty matrices when solving system of equations

Tags: matlab, matrix

So here are the two equations:

(1−e^φ )*P = (1−e^β )*G + (e^β)*(1−e^α)*W

α = φ −β

Where φ = 90 and P,G and W are 1x2 matrices of [2,1], [0,0] and [1.3822, 1.3822] respectively.

Here is my code:

```
function y = RR2CrankAng(P12,G,W1,theta)
syms beta alpha
eqn1 = ((1-exp(theta))*P12) == ((1-exp(beta))*G)+((exp(beta))*(1-exp(alpha))*W1);
eqn2 = alpha == theta - beta;
sol = solve([eqn1, eqn2], [beta12, alpha12]);
xSol = sol.beta12;
ySol = sol.alpha12;
y = [xSol,ySol];
end


CA = RR2CrankAng(P12,G,W1,theta12)
CA =
Empty sym: 0-by-2
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this. I am still learning MATLAB.

Comment: Because `P`, `G`, and `W` are two-element vectors, you technically have three equations with only two variables, and `solve` doesn't seem to like overdetermined systems.  Without more clarification as to what you're after (solving the system for each element of the vectors individually or solving a least-squares problem for all three equations), I can't offer any advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute α = φ −β to the first equation you get

(1−e^φ )*P = (1−e^β )*G + (e^β)*W + (1 − e^φ)*W

You can rearrange it to get

(1−e^φ )*P - G + (e^φ - 1)*W= e^β*(W-G)

This is an over-determined problem. It can be solved for example using the least-squares approach. If you define:

```
A = W-G;
b = (1−e^φ )*P - G + (e^φ - 1)*W);
```

you can get you solution using

```
beta = log(b/A);
```